# Python pyautogui bot pod spacje

Tags: python

Witam czy potrafił by ktoś zrobić bota z pyautogui reagujący na wyświetlane zdjęcie na ekranienp 4 i klika cztery razy spacje ?

Sam trochę próbowałem robić ale nie wyszło nic . Bardzo proszę o pomoc szczerze mówiąc nie mam za dużo linijek kodu więc będą one bez znaczenia tak sądzę. Mam nadzieję że uda mi się coś posklejać z rożnych skryptów i będzie to działać

Comment: [Checkout the docs](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)